# Returning a dictionary in c# in a multi-threaded environment

Tags: c#, concurrency, dictionary, return

I have declared a dictionary of dicionary:

```
Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>> values;
```

I have a getter to get a dictionary at a specific index:

```
public Dictionary<String,String> get(String idx)
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
        return values[moduleName];
    }
}
```

As you can see I am working in a multi-threaded environment.
My question is do I need to return a copy of my dictionary in order to be thread safe like this:

```
public Dictionary<String,String> get(String idx)
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, string>(values[moduleName]);
    }
}
```

If I don't will the class that calls the getter receive a copy (so if I remove this dictionary from my `Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>>` will it still work)?

Cheers,

Thierry.

Comment: You probably shouldn't return the dictionary at all, but if you do, then yes, you need to make a copy while inside a monitor. Can you describe what the purpose of this construct should be?

Comment: Or use a [thread-safe dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx)

Comment: I have to store settings sorted by module. So each module has a dictionary of settings and must be able to get them. A configurationManager keeps all those modules so that they can be easily updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really need to return the dictionary itself, then you're going to need to either have rules for how the threads lock on it (brittle, what if there's a case that doesn't?), use it in a read-only way (dictionary is thread-safe for read-only, but note that this assumes that the code private to the class isn't writing to it any more either), use a thread-safe dictionary (`ConcurrentDictionary` uses striped locking, my [`ThreadSafeDictionary`](http://hackcraft.github.com/Ariadne/documentation/html/T_Ariadne_Collections_ThreadSafeDictionary_2.htm) uses lock-free approaches, and there are different scenarios where one beats the other), or make a copy as you suggest.

Alternatively though, if you expose a method to retrieve or set the ultimate string that is found by the two keys, to enumerate the second-level keys found by a key, and so on, then not only can you control the locking done in one place, but it's got other advantages in cleanness of interface and in freeing implementation from interface (e.g. you could move from lock-based to use of a thread-safe dictionary, or the other way around, without affecting the calling code).

Answer (score 6):

[`Dictionary<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) is not Thread-safe, but [`ConncurrentDictionary<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) is.

The class calling the getter receives a reference, which means it will still be there if you remove it from the `values`-Dictionary as the GC does not clean it as long as you have a reference somewhere, you just can't get it with the getter anymore.

Basicaly that means you have two possibilities when using `Dictionary<>`:

- **return a copy**: Bad idea, because if you change the config you have two different configurations in your app "alive"
- **lock the instance**: this would make it thread-safe, but then use `ConcurrentDictionary<>` as it does exactly that for you

Comment: And remember. Items retrieved from the ConcurrentDictionary are not automatically thread save!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it helped me better understand.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't return a copy, the caller will be able to change the dictionary but this is not a thread safety issue.

There is also a thread safety issue because you don't expose any lock to synchronize writes and reads. For instance, your writer thread can adds/removes a value while the reader thread is working on the same instance.

Yes, you have to return a copy.

Comment: You could simply document that people using the dictionary have to lock it somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, In my case both the caller and the containing class might access the values of the returned dictionary so I will have to go for a copy or a concurrentdictionary.

Comment: @CodingBarfield Yup but you should expose the synclock object you are using to populate the dictionary so everybody is locking on the same object. Locking the dictionary itself is not recommended but it's another topic.

Comment: @CodingBarfield: I would certainly recommend against that. People can forget to do it, and thread issues can be difficult to debug. And this can also introduce deadlocks because the synchronizing object needs to be public. And Guillaume, exposing the lock object publicly is functionally completely equal to locking on the object itself.

Comment: I said to Lock the dictionary in some way. Whether you'll use the Dictionary to Lock it or implement a black box locking is fine by me. I'd go for an implementation that can't be sidestepped by the end-user/programmer.